# Replace or hide words generated from plugin using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a wordpress plugin called "user submitted posts" This allows users to add posts to my site.
The form has one custom field the display the text "Artikelnummer : usp_custom_field : 123156" I would like it to say "Artikelnummer: 123156" but for some reason it also post the usp_scustom_field string name
I have talked to the plugin developer who could not answer this.

So I would like to either remove the string "usp_custom_field". Or "change usp_custom_field" to "Artikelnummer"

Any ideas on how to to this.

Br
Robert

The code

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <p>Artikelnummer : usp_custom_field : 123156</p>
<p>

<div class="CM_Reviews"><div class="cmr_ratings ">
<h2 class="cmr_rating_title">Vad tycker andra</h2>
<div class="cmr_stars"><span class="cmrSingleStar dashicons-star-empty" style="color: #dd9933;"></span><span class="cmrSingleStar dashicons-star-empty" style="color: #dd9933;"></span>
<span class="cmrSingleStar dashicons-star-empty" style="color: #dd9933;"></span>
<span class="cmrSingleStar dashicons-star-empty" style="color: #dd9933;"></span>
<span class="cmrSingleStar dashicons-star-empty" style="color: #dd9933;"></span>
</div>
</div><br>
<div class="cmrRatingHistogramTable">
<style>
progress {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
            }
            progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
                background: transparent;
                border: 1px solid #eeee22;
            }
            progress::-webkit-progress-value {
              background: #eeee22;
            }
            progress::-moz-progress-bar {
              background: #eeee22;
            }</style><div class="cmrTableRow">
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">5 star</span>
                                    <progress class="cmrTableCol" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">0%</span>
                                </div><div class="cmrTableRow">
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">4 star</span>
                                    <progress class="cmrTableCol" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">0%</span>
                                </div><div class="cmrTableRow">
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">3 star</span>
                                    <progress class="cmrTableCol" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">0%</span>
                                </div><div class="cmrTableRow">
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">2 star</span>
                                    <progress class="cmrTableCol" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">0%</span>
                                </div><div class="cmrTableRow">
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">1 star</span>
                                    <progress class="cmrTableCol" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                    <span class="cmrTableCol">0%</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: In general, CSS can not manipulate only _parts_ of a text. It does not apply to text at all in the first place, it applies to elements. You got your full text contained in one single element here, `<p>Artikelnummer : usp_custom_field : 123156</p>` – so there is no realistic way to handle this using CSS only. You will have to use JavaScript, or get the plugin author to fix this (kinda weird, that they said they can’t.)

Comment: The plug-in will be adding this label on the server. They should ideally separate the label and the actual text into two elements. This seems like a very reasonable requirement. Meanwhile you will have to hack together some JS onload I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have means of testing this but it appears that the plugin has some options you can set. In particular:

[image]

Are you auto-displaying the custom field before post content (top radio button clicked)? It would seem like it and if so you can alter what it shows by removing e.g. %%custom_name%%: from the custom field markup.

Sorry I can't test it for you.